# Deque (deck) question

Tags: data-structures, deque

I understand that Deque is "double ended queue" which supports operations from both ends of a queue. My question is how does it work?  e.g. say i have numbers 3,4,2,1,5,6 and i perform
push_back(4)
push_back(3)
push_front(5)
push_front(1)

how will this data appear in deque? will it be like
    3,4,5,1  where Front points to 1 and back to 3?
so if i do pop_back() will it return 3 or 4? (since 3 was pushed before 4.. does it act as a FIFO?)
similarly for pop_front()? 5 or 1?

if I do 
push_back(4)
push_back(3)
push_back(5)
push_back(1)

then I did pop_front() ? what will it return? 4 or 1?

Please help me understand .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/

Also, I use cplusplus.com's reference often for STL questions. It's well written and thorough.

Comment: @ Josh: Thanks !! I think I had wrong impression about this datastructure.. I tried some sample examples and my doubts are clear now.. btw that link is really helpful.. Thanks again